# Values Duplicate When Appending to List

Tags: python, list, append, bounding-box, data-augmentation

I have a list of arrays that I am breaking each index up into a `x` and `y` coordinate. However, the first array is `xmin`, `ymin` and the second array is `xmax`, `ymax`. Then it reapeats. So in my example here, I would have two `xmin`, `ymin` and two `xmax`, `ymax` (two boxes). I then am trying to append all the `xmin`, `ymin`, `xmax`, `ymax` into their own lists. Though when I append them, some of the numbers are being assigned to the wrong spot as well as duplicating and I am unsure why this is happening.

I am using this code to extract bounding boxes from an `.xml` file, augment the values (though in this example because I am using a blur, the original values will not be changed) and then resave them into another `.xml` file. I am having difficulty figuring out how to iterate through the processes. I understand that there is a much shorter way to code this, but this is what I have been able to come up and makes sense to me.

As always, any help would be much appreciated.

My Code:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET2
import imgaug.augmenters as iaa
import imageio
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from imgaug.augmentables.bbs import BoundingBox, BoundingBoxesOnImage

image_x = imageio.imread(r'D:\data\file\007.jpeg')
filename = r'D:\data\file\007.xml'

seq = iaa.GaussianBlur(sigma=(0, 2))

# bounding box colors
GREEN = [0, 255, 0]
ORANGE = [255, 140, 0]
RED = [255, 0, 0]

# extract bounding boxes
tree = ET.parse(filename)
root = tree.getroot()
multiple_annots = []
for box in root.findall('.//bndbox'):
    xmin = int(box.find('xmin').text)
    ymin = int(box.find('ymin').text)
    xmax = int(box.find('xmax').text)
    ymax = int(box.find('ymax').text)
    multiple_annots.append([xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax])

bbx_list = []
for i in multiple_annots:
    index = BoundingBox(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3])
    bbx_list.append(index)
bbs = BoundingBoxesOnImage(bbx_list, shape=image_x.shape)

image_aug, bbs_aug = seq(image=image_x, bounding_boxes=bbs)

xy_pairs_list = []
for boxes in bbs_aug:
    for xy_pairs in boxes:
        xy_pairs_list.append(xy_pairs)
print(xy_pairs_list)
print(bbs_aug)


num = 0
xmin_list = []
ymin_list = []
xmax_list = []
ymax_list = []
for individuals in xy_pairs_list:
    if (num % 2) == 0:
        xmin = individuals[0]
        ymin = individuals[1]
    else:
        xmax = individuals[0]
        ymax = individuals[1]

    xmin_list.append(xmin)
    ymin_list.append(ymin)
    xmax_list.append(xmax)
    ymax_list.append(ymax)

    num = num + 1
print('xmin:', xmin_list, 'ymin:', ymin_list, 'xmax:', xmax_list, 'ymax:', ymax_list)
```

```
bbs_aug output: BoundingBoxesOnImage([BoundingBox(x1=30.0000, y1=1.0000, x2=67.0000, y2=44.0000, label=None), BoundingBox(x1=39.0000, y1=136.0000, x2=73.0000, y2=176.0000, label=None)], shape=(185, 186, 3))

xy_pairs_list output: [array([30.,  1.], dtype=float32), array([67., 44.], dtype=float32), array([ 39., 136.], dtype=float32), array([ 73., 176.], dtype=float32)]

xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax output: xmin: [30.0, 30.0, 39.0, 39.0] ymin: [1.0, 1.0, 136.0, 136.0] xmax: [73, 67.0, 67.0, 73.0] ymax: [176, 44.0, 44.0, 176.0]
```

Desired Output:

```
xmin: [30, 39]
ymin: [1, 136]
xmax: [67, 73]
ymax: [44, 176]
```

EDITS:

XML input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<annotation>
        <folder>jpeg</folder>
        <filename>000.jpeg</filename>   
        <path>C:\jpeg\000.jpeg</path>
        -<source>
                <database>Unknown</database>
        </source>
        -<size>
                <width>185</width>
                <height>185</height>
                <depth>3</depth>
        </size>
        <segmented>0</segmented>
        -<object>
                <name>item</name>
                <pose>Unspecified</pose>
                <truncated>0</truncated>
                <difficult>0</difficult>
        -<bndbox>
                <xmin>30</xmin>
                <ymin>1</ymin>
                <xmax>67</xmax>
                <ymax>44</ymax>
                </bndbox>
        </object>
        -<object>
                <name>item</name>
                <pose>Unspecified</pose>
                <truncated>1</truncated>
                <difficult>0</difficult>
                -<bndbox>
                        <xmin>39</xmin>
                        <ymin>136</ymin>
                        <xmax>73</xmax>
                        <ymax>176</ymax>
                  </bndbox>
        </object>
</annotation>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE - I have only seen the code below `num=0`, since I could find duplicates added  from that code. Not reviewed code above that.

Change your code from the line where you have `num=0` to this :

```
num = 0
xmin_list = []
ymin_list = []
xmax_list = []
ymax_list = []
for individuals in xy_pairs_list:
    if (num % 2) == 0:
        xmin = individuals[0]
        ymin = individuals[1]
        xmin_list.append(int(xmin))
        ymin_list.append(int(ymin))
    else:
        xmax = individuals[0]
        ymax = individuals[1]
        xmax_list.append(int(xmax))
        ymax_list.append(int(ymax))
    num = num + 1
    
print('xmin:', xmin_list, 'ymin:', ymin_list, 'xmax:', xmax_list, 'ymax:', ymax_list)
```

Comment: Yes that works, but I am confused about why you are using the `add` function and not the `append` function? Also, if my values were not intergers...say they were floats, can I just change the value type to anything?

Comment: `add is for set` as `append is for list` . i dint get your second query.

Comment: Sorry, but I just noticed that when I print out `ymin_list` the values are backwards. It needs to read `[1, 136]` not `[136, 1]`.

Comment: It looks as that the first set (`xmin_list`) is the only value that did not flip.

Comment: `sets` dont preserve the order actually. if you're looking for order to be maintained, you should probably check out this - https://pypi.org/project/ordered-set/

Comment: alright ill update my answer in a while so that you dont need to use external library for this.

Comment: i've edited. is this suitable for your case?

Comment: After looking through the project link you sent, I just changed the first few lines to `OrderedSet` instead of `set` and the `xmin` and `ymin` were correct, but the `xmax` and `ymax` were still flipped. Your updated code produces the same results (`xmin/ymin` perfect, but `xmax/ymax` still flipped.

Comment: I am thinking that it might have something to do with my `if else` statement.

Comment: you should probably add how your XML input looks like to your question- for better debugging .

Comment: The input xml shouldn't be the problem though. It should be the `BoundingBoxesOnImage` indicated by the the `bbs_aug`.

Comment: Added the xml file

Comment: there wont be `duplicates`, you `dont need to use orderedset` either. there was a mistake in your `if-else` ,i mean the `appends` should have been inside respective `if-else `.

Comment: okay, yes that does work. So having `xmax` defined earlier in the code was not the issue? Because I hade `xmin` defined as well and I wasn't getting any error with that?

Comment: i guess you will understand better if you change the variable names in `for box in root.findall('.//bndbox')` loop to something other than the names you are using in `for individuals in xy_pairs_list` loop & run your old-code , then run this code.

Answer (score 0):

@Sowjanya R Bhat

Changed

```
xmin_list = set()
ymin_list = set()
xmax_list = set()
ymax_list = set()
```

TO

```
xmin_list = OrderedSet()
ymin_list = OrderedSet()
xmax_list = OrderedSet()
ymax_list = OrderedSet()

print(bbs_aug)
print(print('xmin:', xmin_list, 'ymin:', ymin_list, 'xmax:', xmax_list, 'ymax:', ymax_list)
print(df)
```

```
BoundingBoxesOnImage([BoundingBox(x1=30.0000, y1=1.0000, x2=67.0000, y2=44.0000, label=None), BoundingBox(x1=39.0000, y1=136.0000, x2=73.0000, y2=176.0000, label=None)], shape=(185, 186, 3))

xmin: [30, 39] ymin: [1, 136] xmax: [73, 67] ymax: [176, 44]

   xmin  ymin  xmax  ymax
0    30     1    73   176
1    39   136    67    44
```

Comment: i got an error while running the previous code - saying `xmax` not defined - when the `append` lines were outside the `if-else`

Comment: i tried just keeping an array `xy_pairs_list` , none of the code above that, so i was able to find the error easily when i got `xmax not defined`. you have `xmax` previously defined in your program, n it was appending that old value, when you were expecting new value